custom text field using component in shopware plugin configuration required is not working
I've been tring to create a field using component in plugin configuration, and I've successfully created a field using a component in config.xml . I've managed to save the field data to the database, but I'm facing an issue—I can't seem to make the field required. Any ideas on how we can make a field created using a component required?
\custom\plugins\TestModule\src\Resources\app\administration\src\component\field-bind\field-iban\field-iban-text.html.twig
 <template>
    <sw-text-field 
        :disabled="shouldDisable" 
        name="TestModule.config.iban"
        :value="currentValue"
        @change="onChange"
        @input="onInput"
        :required="isRequired"
        label="IBAN/QR-IBAN Number for Classic format"
    />
</template>

\custom\plugins\TestModule\src\Resources\app\administration\src\component\field-bind\field-iban\index.js
const {Component} = Shopware; 
import template from './field-iban-text.html.twig'
    
Component.register('field-iban-text', 
    { 
    template,
    props: {
        value: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            default: '',
        },
    },
    methods: {
        disableField() {
            return this.$attrs.myConfig.elements.find(element => element.config?.specialType === 'disable')['name']
        },
        onChange(event) {
            this.$emit('change', value || '');
        },
        onInput(value) {
            this.$emit('input', value);
        },
    },
    computed: {
        shouldDisable() {
            if(this.$attrs.actualConfigData[this.disableField()] === 'SCOR'){
                return true;
            }else { 
                return false;
            }
        },
        isRequired(){
            if(this.$attrs.actualConfigData[this.disableField()] === 'QRR'){
                return true;
            }else { 
                return false;
            }
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            currentValue: this.value,
        };
    },
    
    watch: {
        value(value) {
            this.currentValue = value;
        },
    }, 
});

